# Xcode won't close

Tags: c++, macos, xcode11.5

I am currently a student using Xcode on Mac. Every time I try to close or quit Xcode, I get a message that says:

"You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “unordered_set” is in.
You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate. Only the duplicate will include your changes."

I can't even shut down my computer because that message always pops up. When I click "Duplicate", nothing appears to happen. Even after I click "Duplicate", I cannot quit Xcode or shut down my computer. Does anybody know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably edited a header file "unordered_set" that you included using "Auto-Fix issues" feature in Xcode .

So go over all the files that you've included and undo the changes.

Use control + command + click on the header filename to jump into files.